# Taylor expansion of a function containing QPochhammer[q, q, n]

Tags: bugs, special-functions, series-expansion

I want to get the following series expansion:

```
Series[QPochhammer[q, q, 3], {q, 0,4}]
```

but in *Mathematica* 11.0, I obtain the following gibberish:

[image: bad output]

There weren't any problems of this kind in *Mathematica* 8.0.

The following example with the infinite product

```
Series[QPochhammer[q, q], {q, 0, 4}]
```

works perfectly fine, producing the series

[image: good result]

Documentation regarding `QPochhammer` can be found [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QPochhammer.html).

> Q: What causes this problem with finite products and how to avoid it?

Comment: `Series[QPochhammer[q, q, 3], {q, 0, 4}]` yields `SeriesData[q, 0, {1, -1, -1, 0, 1}, 0, 5, 1]` in V10.0.1. That gibberish, of course, is *Mathematica* evaluating the formal power series of that function assuming that it doesn't know anything about the symbol `QPochhammer`. But clearly it does (since it knew it before), so this strikes me as likely a bug introduced somewhere between 10.0.1 and 11.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because somewhere between v10.0 and v10.3, the seventh definition of `QPochhammer` was modified to check that the second argument does *not* depend on the expansion parameter.

To restore previous behavior, clear the seventh definition,

```
(*Triggers loading of definitions*)
Series[QPochhammer[0, x, 3], {x, 0, 1}];

(*Unprotect*)
Unprotect[QPochhammer];

QPochhammer /: 
 System`Private`InternalSeries[
   HoldPattern[QPochhammer][System`SeriesDump`w_, 
    System`SeriesDump`q_, 
    System`SeriesDump`k_Integer?Positive], {System`SeriesDump`z_, 
    System`SeriesDump`p_, System`SeriesDump`n_Integer}] /; 
 Internal`DependsOnQ[System`SeriesDump`w, System`SeriesDump`z] && ! 
    Internal`DependsOnQ[{System`SeriesDump`q, System`SeriesDump`p}, 
    System`SeriesDump`z] =.
```

Then add the definition from earlier versions,

```
QPochhammer /: 
 System`Private`InternalSeries[
   HoldPattern[QPochhammer][System`SeriesDump`w_, 
    System`SeriesDump`q_, 
    System`SeriesDump`k_Integer?Positive], {System`SeriesDump`z_, 
    System`SeriesDump`p_, System`SeriesDump`n_Integer}] /; 
  Internal`DependsOnQ[System`SeriesDump`w, System`SeriesDump`z] := 
 Module[{System`SeriesDump`lim, System`SeriesDump`ord, 
   System`SeriesDump`qq, System`SeriesDump`ww}, 
  System`SeriesDump`lim = 
   System`SeriesDump`getExpansionPoint[System`SeriesDump`w, 
    System`SeriesDump`z, 
    System`SeriesDump`p]; (System`SeriesDump`ord = 
     Min[System`SeriesDump`k, 
      System`SeriesDump`AdjustExpansionOrder[System`SeriesDump`w, 
       System`SeriesDump`lim, System`SeriesDump`z, 
       System`SeriesDump`p, System`SeriesDump`n]]; 
    System`SeriesDump`ww = 
     System`Private`InternalSeries[
      System`SeriesDump`w, {System`SeriesDump`z, System`SeriesDump`p, 
       System`SeriesDump`n}]; 
    System`SeriesDump`qq = 
     System`Private`InternalSeries[
      System`SeriesDump`q, {System`SeriesDump`z, System`SeriesDump`p, 
       System`SeriesDump`n}]; 
    1 + Plus @@ 
      Table[(-System`SeriesDump`ww)^
        System`SeriesDump`m System`SeriesDump`qq^
        Binomial[System`SeriesDump`m, 2] QBinomial[
         System`SeriesDump`k, System`SeriesDump`m, 
         System`SeriesDump`qq], {System`SeriesDump`m, 
        System`SeriesDump`ord}]) /; System`SeriesDump`lim === 0];

Protect[QPochhammer];
```

Now we get the desired behavior,

```
Series[QPochhammer[q, q, 3], {q, 0, 4}]
```

> [image: Desired result]

**Warning** The seventh definition was modified in later releases probably because someone discovered that it leads to incorrect results in some cases.  Proceed with caution.

Comment: An alternative is to use `QPochhammer[q + O[q]^5, q, 3]`

Answer (score 7):

An easier method is to perform a preliminary application of `FunctionExpand[]`:

```
Series[QPochhammer[q, q, 3] // FunctionExpand, {q, 0, 4}]
   1 - q - q^2 + q^4 + O[q]^5
```