# Problem with QPochhammer or SeriesCofficient?

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion, number-theory

In version 10.2.0, I calculated the number of integer partitions of `n` into exactly `k` distinct parts with no part exceeding `m` by using `PochhammerDistinct[n,k,m]`.

```
$Version
```

> 10.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 6, 2015)

```
PochhammerDistinct[n_, k_, m_] := 
   Coefficient[SeriesCoefficient[QPochhammer[-t*z, z, m], {z, 0, n}], t^k]
```

This function is based on the answer by @ciao [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91613/improving-speed-of-code-computing-number-of-nonrepeating-partitions).

For example, there are 9 partitions of 28 into exactly 4 distinct parts with no part exceeding 10.

```
PochhammerDistinct[28, 4, 10]
```

> 9

```
Select[IntegerPartitions[28, {4}, Range[10]], Length[Union[#]] == 4 &]
```

> {{10, 9, 8, 1}, {10, 9, 7, 2}, {10, 9, 6, 3}, {10, 9, 5, 4}, {10, 8, 
>     7, 3}, {10, 8, 6, 4}, {10, 7, 6, 5}, {9, 8, 7, 4}, {9, 8, 6, 5}}

However, in versions 10.3.1, 10.4.1, and 11.0.1 for 64-bit Linux, the same function gives the following.

```
PochhammerDistinct[28, 4, 10]
```

[image: weird Pochhammer]

How to I convert this new answer into the integer 9? Is this a bug? Does the weird functional form persist in v11.1.0?

Comment: Try `PochhammerDistinct[n_, k_, m_] := Coefficient[SeriesCoefficient[FunctionExpand[QPochhammer[-t z, z, m]], {z, 0, n}], t^k]`. This is apparently the same problem as [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139388).

Comment: @J.M. - your approach works with version 11.0.1 and 11.1.0 for Mac OS X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted, the workaround needed is to apply `FunctionExpand[]` to the finite $q$-Pochhammer symbol:

```
PochhammerDistinct[n_, k_, m_] := Block[{t, z},
   Coefficient[SeriesCoefficient[FunctionExpand[QPochhammer[-t z, z, m]], {z, 0, n}], t^k]]
```

From here,

```
PochhammerDistinct[28, 4, 10]
   9
```